# Failed build Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I have downloaded a Demo project from the spring Initializer website. Without adding any code or editing any of the files I am getting the following error when building for the first time.

```
Could not initialize class sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile
```

I have tried looking for similar issues on stack overflow but their answers couldn't apply to my situation.

Comment: Did you choose the wrong java version when generating your project? That class has been removed in Java 9, IIRC

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I chose Java 11. What do you mean by wrong?

Comment: I mean, in the initializer did you choose the java version corresponding to the one you are going to use to compile your program?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yeap. I use java 11 with JDK 11 and I downloaded the Java11 file.